# Getting webpages to extend down to bottom of page in mobile browsers (on-screen keyboard issue)

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I am creating a webpage that contains a google map that extends down to the bottom of the page.

However there seems to be a problem with this in some mobile browsers. If the onscreen keyboard is present just before the page loads, the map doesnt extend down to the bottom of the screen but just goes to where the top of the on-screen keyboard was.

See code below.
To test it, load up the page, then click on the browser's address bar and hit 'ENTER' on the onscreen keyboard. The page will be refreshed but this time shrunk in height.

Doesnt affect all browsers - problem exists on android browser on my Samsung GTi5500 (android 2.2) but not on my Freelander tablet (android 4).

What it aught to look like...

[image: what it aught to look like]

On-screen keyboard up...

[image: on-screen keyboard]

When page reloads, you get this...

[image: what-you get - white space at bottom]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
            zoom: 16,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.312, -3.004)
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

These all report a height of 128px - i.e. confirms that the browser thinks that the page height is short (it aught to be 401px for the browser visible area).

```
       screen.height
       $(window).height
       document.height
       jQuery(document).height()
       $("html").height()
       $("body").height()
```

Comment: I don't know answer but I have suggestion for you. Please add appropriate tags to your question. It seems like you have issue regarding GoogleMap, AndroidApp, etc.

Comment: @Nizam Kazi It is not a google maps issue. It happens with any absolutely positioned or fixed positioned (maybe more I dont know). (I felt the question was long enough without adding more details). I mention google maps in case anyone suggests a solution and that is not appropriate for google maps. Why do you say AndroidApps? It is not an android app - it is a webpage.

Comment: That's just a helpful suggestion from @NizamKazi from the best practices. I'm digging into your issue, BTW.

Comment: Question: why set viewport's maximum-scale? Suggestion: turn off all scaling after `initial-scale`.

Comment: thanks @mike. Do you mean why am removing all user controlled scalability? This is because with google maps you already have a built in scaling and you need to stop the browser and gogole maps scaling competing with each other. Also I have a menus bar at the top (removed in simplified case above) with fixed positioning which only seems to work with android 2.2 if you fix the scaling.